# My design that requires me to have more than a 1000 literal predicate values for a SQL is flawed. How do I fix it?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, jdbc, oracle11g

I have list of 100 000 employee names in java and I need to fetch Details for all these employees from database (which has around 400 000 Employee Details). I tried it with IN operator but it takes 10-15 minutes to do the fetch. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: what's lakh? is it thousand?

Comment: @sharonbn [Google it](https://www.google.com/search?q=lakh): 100000

Comment: Little bit slower than what?

Comment: I have list of one lakh employee but IN operator support only 1 thousand.

Comment: @JamesZ i am looking for some better solution than this, as it is taking time to execute.

Comment: @JamesZ well.. means it is taking much time.

Comment: @MANJITKUMAR Well try to be clear with your questions, and also please don't use Indian measurements.

Answer (score 1):

Most DBMS's have a limit to the number of values an `IN` clause may have.

You have a few choices:

1. Run separate `SELECT` statement for each name.
2. Run separate `SELECT` statement for each name, but [batch them](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#addBatch%28%29).
   Limit batch size to reasonable number, e.g. 1000. Larger batches use more memory and doesn't improve performance.
3. Chop list of names into blocks of 1000, and run `SELECT ... IN` for each block.

If you're already doing #3, then you're doing it the best way you can.

---

Splitting the task into chunks of 1000 (`SELECT` batches or block of `IN` lists), will not be much different in performance from doing 100000 in one operation.

*Unless* you don't have an index on the name column, so the database has to do a full table scan. If that is the case, then chunking it would cause many full table scans, and that would be bad.

Solution #1: Create an index. If you do name lookups of tables with 100000+ records, you really(!) need an index.

Solution #2: Insert all names into a temporary staging table, then do `SELECT ... WHERE name IN ( SELECT name FROM temptable )`, which is what [@JamesZ suggested in the comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37096816/my-design-that-requires-me-to-have-more-than-a-1000-literal-predicate-values-for/37096995?noredirect=1#comment61737246_37096995) below. This would ensure that only one full table scan is needed.

Strongly suggest solution #1.

Comment: One option would be to load the customers into a table and use that

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for your answer, Yes i tried the #3, but it seems slower to me that's why i post this question to get  some better approach.

Comment: @JamesZ That would require 100000 `INSERT` statements, so what would be gained by that?

Comment: @MANJITKUMAR Slower than *what*? You didn't answer that in question comments. You said *"taking time to execute"* and *"taking much time"*, but *"slower"* means you're comparing it to something else that is faster, so what would that be? And yes, it will take time to lookup 100000 names.

Comment: @JamesZ what is the meaning, to load customers into table,are you saying to insert 100 000 record into table and then load it?As 400 000 record are already present in Employee table.

Comment: @Andreas i am not comparing it to something, it is taking time around 10-15 min to execute but i want to take it to around 5 min or less.

Comment: @JamesZ Added your suggestion to answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MANJITKUMAR If you're not comparing to something, then don't use the word "slower". Say "too slow for my needs", or something like that. Question: Are your needs reasonable? Doable? How do you know?

Comment: @Andreas I was thinking more about bulk operations like sql loader, not sure if anything like that can be done in java

Comment: @JamesZ Closest in Java would be batching of insert statements. Minimizes round-trips to server, which is the main performance issue with something like this. But you are right, [SQL Loader](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/testcontent/sql-loader-overview-095816.html) straight to temp table would be faster.